# SWT- How to change ProgressBar color in Windows?

Tags: java, swt, windowbuilder

Is there a way to change the color of a ProgressBar's bars in SWT?  `.setForeground()` doesn't seem to work.

If there is not a way to change the color programmatically, is there a way to change ProgressBar's color using the WindowBuilder GUI tools?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't change the color of the progress bar on Windows.

Comment: See [Eclipse bug 168738](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=168738) for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SWT there are 3 built-in states, each represented by a color:

```
progressBar.setState(SWT.ERROR); //Red Fill color. Useful when the task is aborted.
```

This state does not support an indeterminate progress bar style ([SWT.INDETERMINATE](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=1898)).

```
progressBar.setState(SWT.PAUSED); //Yellow Fill color.
```

This state will pause the indeterminate progress bar animation.

```
progressBar.setState(SWT.NORMAL); //Default state and color as controlled by OS.
```

Comment: I was originally hoping to determine the color on my own, but three colors is better than one.

Comment: Amir Afghani was right about you can't change the color, unfortunately this is all you can do in SWT.

Comment: I just noticed that this works on my PC, but doesn't work on my Mac

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the color of the progress bar on Windows using SWT.

Answer (score 0):

You can now, using JProgressBar.setForeground( Color )

Comment: looks like a Swing component to me - not SWT as the OP requested :-(