# How to change color of SWT eclipse progress bar of splash screen from green to customized one

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, splash-screen

I need to customize the splash screen progress bar of my eclipse product . 
How to change color of SWT eclipse progress bar of splash screen from green to customized color

Comment: You may not be able to change this. On some platforms (macOS for example) the `ProgressBar` control foreground color is set by the system theme and can't be changed.

Comment: Indeed you can't. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674678/swt-how-to-change-progressbar-color-in-windows

Comment: ok thanks for info and progress bar  disappears middle of bar  and opens . what can we do to show progress bar till the end of bar.

Comment: @Alex Are you sure you are not referring to an outdated question that no longer applies?

Comment: @howlger It is certainly the case that ProgressBar.setForeground doesn't do anything on macOS (and neither does setState)

Comment: You can implement your own splash screen with your own progress bar via the [`org.eclipse.ui.splashHandlers`](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_splashHandlers.html) extension point.

Comment: @greg-449 See [Eclipse bug 168738](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=168738) for details. I don't think it's a good idea to use as a proof another stack overflow question that might be outdated or have wrong answers.